# Store reactive (ref) value in pinia

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity, pinia

I have a reactive value, which I want to store in a pinia store.

```js
const data = ref({});
async function loadData() {
  fetch("...")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => (data.value = json));
}
loadData();

const myDataStore = useMyDataStore();
const { myData } = storeToRefs(myDataStore);

// Here I want to store data in the store, reactively
myData.value = data.value;
```

But when I do this, the reactivity is lost. How do you store the value in the store, so that `myData` is updated every time `data` is updated?

Answer (score 0):

You should define your store like this:

```js
import {defineStore} from 'pinia'

export const useMyDataStore = defineStore('myStore', {
    state: () => ({
        myData: {}
    }),
    actions: {
        update(value){
            Object.assign(this.myData, value);
        }
    }
})
```

Then use like

```js
const data = ref({});
async function loadData() {
  fetch("...")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => (data.value = json));
}
loadData().then();

const myDataStore = useMyDataStore();

watch(data, (newVal) => {
    myDataStore.update(newVal);
}
```

Comment: I think should be `myData: {}` instead of `myData = {}`

Comment: loadData(); should be await loadData();

Answer (score -1):

Use `watch()` to look for changes on your ref data object. On change call the `myDataStore.update(newData)`:

```
watch(data, (newData) => {
   myDataStore.update(newData)
})
```

The state in pinia should be updated